# Amp logo error google structured data testing tool

Tags: amp-html

I added a logo to amp pages and now I am getting

"A value for the logo field is required"

error in google structured data testing tool here: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=http:%2F%2Fwww.timesnews.co.uk%2F9516-lg-g-pad-iii-8-0-launched-us-korea-240%2Famp%2F

How to fix this error and a warning showing below this page?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your "publisher" field in your json does not have a "logo" property:

Your JSON:

```
"publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Times News UK, World, Gadgets, Mobiles News"},...
```

Correct format of "publisher" json:

```
"publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Times News UK, World, Gadgets, Mobiles News", "logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"http://...","width":"XXX","height":"YYY"}},...
```

The logo property needs to be within the publisher object.

Comment: How to set JSON Correctly?

Comment: @ZainZaheer06 answering that question is out of scope for this answer. There are plenty of JSON formatters and checkers online that can help you. Just search for "JSON formatter" and then paste in your JSON to see what you may be doing wrong.